# Libgdx - Having one Entity partially exempt from Phsyics

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, box2d

I'm using LibGDX to make a mobile game, now I'm facing a certain issue.

I have a certain Entity which can collide with the wall, when this happens the wall receives a certain force which then causes it to go off the screen and not be positioned properly anymore.

I have tried using LibGDX's isSensor variable but after doing that my Entity crosses straight through the wall.

How can I make it so the wall does stop the Entity from moving through but isn't affected itself by the force of the Entity?

I'm using the physics body editor for my colission shapes as they are not in normal geometrical formats.

Thank you,

Rene

Comment: I have resolved my issue by using a KinematicBody in LibGdX.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make the wall static.

I'm not sure how you do it using the physics body editor as I've never used it, but here's some code I wrote a while back that does something similar...

```
private void buildRoom()
{
    Vector2[] roomCorners = new Vector2[]{new Vector2(0f, 0f),
                                                 new Vector2(0f, ROOM_HEIGHT),
                                                 new Vector2(ROOM_WIDTH, ROOM_HEIGHT),
                                                 new Vector2(ROOM_WIDTH, 0f)};

    ChainShape roomShape = new ChainShape();
    try
    {
        roomShape.createLoop(roomCorners);
        BodyDef roomDef = new BodyDef();
        roomDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        Body room = world.createBody(roomDef);
        room.createFixture(roomShape, 0);
    } finally
    {
        roomShape.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.

Unfortunately when I made the Density 0 it created the opposite effect, the Wall gets pushed out completely right away, that makes the problem worse.

I could obviously add a ridiculous amount of Density but I don't believe this is the right approach to take.

Comment: I think the density is not relevant. You need to make it a static body.

Comment: The density of 0 was something I read somewhere. Sounds like it's not right, though so I'll edit and remove that part.

Comment: A static body didn't work in my case as the walls are impacted by a downwards velocity, I have however fixed my problem by using a KinameticBody, it's not impacted by force however it is by velocity.